# How to logout facebook connect user with Facebook Developer Toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, fdt

How can I logout or disconnect a Facebook user in the Facebook connect session?

I'm using the Facebook developer toolkit. After using "connectSession.Logout()", the method "connectSession.IsConnected()" is still returning "true". Have I done something wrong?

EDIT: Now, I know that you can't logout a user just from the Facebook connect site. A user can be logged out only from the entire Facebook site. How can I do that with Facebook Developer Toolkit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

In answer to your second question, just log them out using the JavaScript SDK:

```
FB.logout(function(response)
{
    // user is logged out
    // redirect to local logout script
});
```

Here's also an answer I made before that should help. This answer is for the older javascript and php SDK, but it should still apply.

[How to log out users using Facebook Connect in PHP and Zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386557/how-to-log-out-users-using-facebook-connect-in-php-and-zend/1386749#1386749)