# How to logout from facebook connect in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

i can't logout a user when it's connected through facebook connect. 
I'm using the facebook developer toolkit. 
Anyone know how to "disconnect" a user  ?

Answer (score 3):

There are functions to logout a user:

```
FB.Connect.logout
```

and

```
FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect
```

> These calls log the user out of both your site and Facebook. The latter method also redirects the user once the logout dialog closes.

You might want to checkout this thread as well:

[How to log out users using Facebook Connect in PHP and Zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386557/how-to-log-out-users-using-facebook-connect-in-php-and-zend)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i'm using a server side control. Can i call it from server side code ? 
If yes, how ? Thank you for your patience !

Comment: @stighy You could always just write the javascript to the Page's startup javascript so it runs as soon as you server up the page.

Answer (score 0):

I use the javascript function FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect; The redirect sends them to somewhere we can kill the session on our side.