# App Session still exist after facebook logout

Tags: php, facebook, session, sdk

I'm new to Facebook API and I already search a LOT to solved this problem but I'm not successful in finding one.
The browser is still getting the cookies of the last session even after the user have logged out of facebook.

Here's how it is done:
1. User logged in to facebook.
2. Open application.
3. Logged out of facebook.
3. Open application (not logged in) and the application will load with an error

Message: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=157847364248123|2.pqWqIaCD8BKobvG_kJy9sA__.3600.1295859600-100001714363073|QfoJpTH-slOry2K1FepeyW8z5f8) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

I think I need to clear cookies when the user ticked logout in facebook but I don't know how to do it in PHP SDK. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be previously solved here: [How to log out users using Facebook Connect in PHP and Zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386557/how-to-log-out-users-using-facebook-connect-in-php-and-zend/1386749#1386749)

Comment: where did it get $this->getConfig()->getAppId();?? I looked at the facebook php sdk for same function but I have'nt found one.

Comment: I never used the PHP SDK, but I believe you have to define it yourself somewhere globally with `define('APP_ID', '12346789');`

Answer (score 1):

I tried catching user logout from facebook through Javascript, then the JS will redirect to the controller function which clears cookies, but that doesn't worked for me. My app still getting old session which causes my app to load with errors even when the user is logged out.

But I got my problem solved by just adding these two lines of code to my session checking:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
```

When this checking fails, the page will be redirected to facebook login page. This is how my code looks like:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$me = NULL;

if ($session)
{
    try
    {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

         /// OTHER PROCESS

        $this->load->view('app_page', $data);
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        error_log($e);
        $this->output->set_header("Location: http://www.facebook.com, TRUE, 302");
    }
}
else
{
    /// GO TO PERMISSION REQUEST
}
```